# How can I capture someone uses select statement in sql database ( Sql Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to capture someone read data from database. I am thinking capture select by trigger. I tried following code. But it fails because select_table is not right type of event

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_tblCheckingAccount_ForUpdate
ON ALL SERVER
FOR SELECT_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @MYData XML
    SELECT @MyData=EVENTDATA()
    SELECT @MYData

    INSERT INTO ReadOnBranchReport 
    VALUES 
    (
        'User Name '+@MYData.value('/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(270)')+
        ' read The Data from '+@MYData.value('/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(270)')+
        'table'

    )
END
```

I don't know what is right type of event for select.

Comment: Could you provide an MRE form the code you already have? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hi, I edited the question. please check the body of question 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to setup [audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers don't work for `select`. You have two options:

1. Implement a **stored procedure** that returns the data while logging the access event. If you're worried about users bypassing the stored procedure, use security permissions to prevent them from accessing the table except by the stored procedure.
2. Implement **audit**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15